How to force *mongo.SingleResult decode error?
I have been trying to force error for the decode method in order to test it with no success. How can I set a result *mongo.SingleResult value to force fail on decoding? ?
I have tried by creating a cursor with error CreateWriteErrorsResponse, but it is not the return of a cursor with error what I expect but the decode of the result to fail.
I'm setting responses for the cursor by adding some bson.D{} expecting to make the decode broke but I couldn't find any value that forces the return of an error, this is how I am testing:
func TestRepository_Get_Bad_Parse_Error(t *testing.T) {
    mock := mtest.New(t, mtest.NewOptions().ClientType(mtest.Mock))
    mock.Cleanup(func() { mock.Client = nil })

    mock.Run("BadParseError", func(mock *mtest.T) {
        repository := shops.NewRepositoryImpl(mock.DB.Collection(dependencies.KvsShopsCollection))
        mock.AddMockResponses(mtest.CreateCursorResponse(0,"foo.bar",
                mtest.FirstBatch,
                bson.D{
                    {"_d", "660a81b04f151ed0f710192"},
                    {"mock", "test"},
                },),)
        shopTest, err := repository.Get(context.TODO(), "65f4973cb7942e76f0aa85c5")

        assert.EqualValues(mock, models.Shop{}, shopTest)
        assert.NotNil(t, err)
    })
}

This is the function to the DB:
func (storage *shopsRepository) Get(ctx context.Context, shopID string) (models.Shop, apierrors.ApiError) {
    var mdls models.Shop
    result, err := gonosql.Get(ctx, storage.Collection, shopID)
    if err != nil {
        return models.Shop{}, apierrors.NewBadRequestApiError(fmt.Sprintf(errorInDB, "Get") + ": " + err.Error())
    }
    if errors.Is(result.Err(), mongo.ErrNoDocuments) {
        return models.Shop{}, apierrors.NewNotFoundApiError(fmt.Sprintf(errorNotFound, shopID))
    }
    if result.Err() != nil {
        return models.Shop{}, apierrors.NewInternalServerApiError(fmt.Sprintf(errorInDB, "Get"), result.Err())
    }
    err = result.Decode(&mdls)
    if err != nil {
        return models.Shop{}, apierrors.NewInternalServerApiError(fmt.Sprintf(errorInDB, "Get"), err)
    }
    return mdls, nil
}

